# jQuery Ajax POST response - knowing which form submitted?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Supposing I had a multi-form page such as:

```
<form id="A" class="jaxy" ... />
<form id="B" class="jaxy" ... />
<form id="C" class="jaxy" ... />
```

Then I have some JQuery

```
$('.jaxy').live('submit', function() {
  $(this).startLoadingSpinner;
  $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), $(this).stopLoadingSpinner, "script");
  return false;
});
```

When a "jaxy" form is submitted there's an Ajax post request and the server might respond with some script like the following:

```
// The code I wish I had...
// If there was an error with the form it might respond...
$(whichever_form_posted).replaceWith("<form id="B" class="jaxy" .../>")
// or if everything went well it might...
$(whichever_form_posted).empty();
alert("Everything is right with the world! Give yourself a pat on the back.");
```

The trouble I'm obviously having is knowing which form submitted the post request in the first place. The way is see it I have 3 possible routes:

1. I could potentially send a DOM selector in the POST params? or
2. I could request a HTML response and insert the response data BUT as shown above I *might* not want to replace so this isn't really an option for me.
3. **My preference** somehow create a $.fn.function prototype in the response that could be called on the submitting element. This would have to be carefully scoped or unique so that any subsequent form submissions didn't redefine the function.

I'm really struggling to see a way around this and I would appreciate any thoughts on this. It's not necessarily relevant but I'm using this in a RoR environment and the POST request is a .js response to a RESTful controller action. More of a jQuery question that a RoR one I guess.

Kind regards,

Kevin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not mentioned what appears to be the most obvious technique: a hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="foo">
```

Comment: :) This was the first thing I was going to try. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: i should add that the only thing that stopped me from doing this in the first place is that I don't like to modify the HTML in order to suit the JS but you're correct - it does seem like the obvious solution.

Comment: If you want to set with JavaScript, you can also append `this.id` to the AJAX call. It can make a good GET param if you already pass info through POST.

Comment: About the reputation, you can always review your past questions and accept some of the answers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully i understand your problem correctly. What you want to know is which form is actually submitting the data. Here is my code suggestion :

```
$('.jaxy').live('submit', function() {
  // get the id of the form that makes this request
  var form_id = $(this).attr('id');

  $(this).startLoadingSpinner;

  $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function(data){ 
        alert(form_id); 
    }, "script");

  return false;
});
```

Comment: that's kind of what I want to do except that the script response would need to create a function that I could call on that element.

i.e. (This syntax will be all over the place as I'm no JS expert but hopefully it will show the intent)

$(form_id).returnedScript.someFuncInReturnedScript